# Javascript string literals: are they a reference type or a value type?

Tags: javascript

I know that this question is a bit pointless due to the fact that in Javascript strings are **immutable**, so in a sense knowing whether they are modeled as a  *value type* or a *reference type* is not so useful.

So, takes my question just as a curiosity: are string literals in Javascript a value type or a reference type ?

Because I know that there is a lot of confusion with regards to terminology, I would like to clarify what I mean by *reference type* and *value type*.

When I say *reference type* I mean a type for which the values assigned to variables are actually references to objects in memory. This happens with object literals for instance:

```
const myObject = {foo: "bar"};
const anotherObject = myObject; // both the variables myObject and anotherObject are references to the same memory address. Only one object exists in memory
```

On the other side when I say *value type* I mean a type for which the values assigned to variables are the real data representing the intended value of the variable (not a pointer to a memory address containing the real data). This happens with booleans for instance:

```
const myBoolean = true;
const anotherBoolean = true; // here both of the variables contain the actual data (which is the intended boolean value of the variable). There are two distinct and independent sequences of bytes representing the two distinct and independent boolean data in memory
```

**WHY I DO NOT THINK THIS IS A DUPLICATE**

The linked question is somewhat related to mine, but I'm asking specifically about how strings are modeled in memory in a Javascript program, while the linked question asks why it is possible to call methods on string literals and is more related with the idea of *boxing* explained in its answers.

**IMPORTANT NOTE FOR EVERY READER: THIS QUESTION IS ACTUAL POINTLESS DUE TO IMMUTABILITY**

See [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm) for a complete explanations.

Here I just report a few quotes from the article linked above:

> Since strings are immutable, our original question is moot: there is no way to tell if strings are passed by value or by reference. We can assume that, for efficiency, JavaScript is implemented so that strings are passed by reference, but in actuality it doesn't matter, since it has no practical bearing on the code we write.

And again, at the bottom of the article:

> This experiment demonstrates that strings are compared by value. This may be surprising to some programmers. In C, C++, and Java, strings are reference types and are compared by reference. If you want to compare the actual contents of two strings, you must use a special method or function. JavaScript, however, is a higher-level language and recognizes that when you compare strings, you most often want to compare them by value. Thus, despite the fact that, for efficiency, JavaScript strings are (presumably) copied and passed by reference, they are compared by value.

Long story short: the actual implementation probably depends on the particular javascript interpreter (in other words this is an implementation detail). It seems reasonable, for efficiency reasons, to model strings as reference types, but again it probably depends on the actual interpreter used. Anyway, **strings immutability makes pointless this whole discussion and this is just a matter for curiosity**.

Comment: Strings are value type in js.

Comment: @NenadVracar why the question has been unrated ? I don't see anything wrong in it

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote.

Comment: Just a small clarification regarding to the phrasing: at the end, everything points to a memory address.. just saying.

Comment: Strings are just like booleans and numbers.

Comment: string literals are _not_ of type `String` - `"x" instanceof String === false`.

Comment: @MaheerAli that's not a useful distinction, since booleans and numbers also have "Object" equivalents that are reference types. try e.g. new Number(1) !== new Number(1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you declare strings like

```
const a = 'a' 
const b = 'a'
a === b // true
```

then they are value types.

However JS also has a `String` constructor, so if you do:

```
const a = new String('a');
const b = new String('a');
a === b // false
```

In this case they'll be compared by reference. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: thanks because this refers to a related idea which is the dicotomy between string literals and the String constructor. Really useful.

Comment: @EnricoMassone yup - string literals are "value types", the result of `new String()` is a reference type.   That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: IMHO this is incorrect, because strings are allocated on heap. string is a special reference type that acts like a value type in equality operator. When a string is passed to a function, its reference is passed to the function not a copy of its value. Copying a whole string value to a function each time the function is called kills performance. Suppose you have 100KB size string. Is it logical for javascript engine to copy it each time you assign your variable to another variable or pass it to a function?

Comment: I tested a small script and checked Developer Tools's Memory tab. I'm now completely sure that strings are reference type.